# Random freezes with AMD Ryzen on Linux

Tags: linux, debian

Since I've bought an AMD Ryzen 7 1700 I've been having constant freezes while using Linux.

Recently I had a freeze with Debian 10. The last line I could find on my kern.log before the freeze is `IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx20e71702e354: link is not ready`.

I never had this problem with Windows in the same machine. I also use the same software in other computers and I *never* had this problem.

I doubt that what I found in my kern.log is something to be concerned of, so I'm really lost. Could it be my motherboard that doesn't work properly? Power supply? So why it never happened on Windows even while playing very heavy games like GTA V and Battlefield V?

After adding `processor.max_cstate=0 rcu_nocbs=0-15` kernel parameters the freezes are drastically less frequent but they happen from time to time.

I thought that it wasn't going to happen again after adding the kernel parameters since it reduced the frequency of them, until it did just now and I had data loss again. I don't want to go too personal here but I need to explicit that it is very annoying to be working and suddenly lose your important work data. I just want to fix this problem for good and not to worry about it anymore.

#### About the freeze

It is always the same thing, I'm still able to see the screen but can't move the cursor or change Num Lock, the computer doesn't come back until I power reset it manually.

#### Kernel logging

```
Jun 20 22:23:53 victor-pc kernel: [39277.423128] mt7601u: probe of 3-4:1.0 failed with error -5
Jun 20 22:23:53 victor-pc kernel: [39277.423327] usb 3-4: USB disconnect, device number 112
Jun 20 22:23:55 victor-pc kernel: [39279.563013] usb 3-4: new high-speed USB device number 113 using xhci_hcd
Jun 20 22:23:55 victor-pc kernel: [39279.721135] usb 3-4: New USB device found, idVendor=148f, idProduct=7601, bcdDevice= 0.00
Jun 20 22:23:55 victor-pc kernel: [39279.721140] usb 3-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jun 20 22:23:55 victor-pc kernel: [39279.721143] usb 3-4: Product: 802.11 n WLAN
Jun 20 22:23:55 victor-pc kernel: [39279.721144] usb 3-4: Manufacturer: MediaTek
Jun 20 22:23:55 victor-pc kernel: [39279.721146] usb 3-4: SerialNumber: 1.0
Jun 20 22:23:56 victor-pc kernel: [39280.479357] mt7601u: probe of 3-4:1.0 failed with error -5
Jun 20 22:23:56 victor-pc kernel: [39280.479587] usb 3-4: USB disconnect, device number 113
Jun 20 22:24:00 victor-pc kernel: [39284.686987] usb 3-4: new high-speed USB device number 114 using xhci_hcd
Jun 20 22:24:05 victor-pc kernel: [39289.255011] usb 3-4: new high-speed USB device number 115 using xhci_hcd
Jun 20 22:24:11 victor-pc kernel: [39295.147322] usb 3-4: new high-speed USB device number 116 using xhci_hcd
Jun 20 22:24:17 victor-pc kernel: [39300.782962] usb 3-4: new high-speed USB device number 117 using xhci_hcd
Jun 20 22:24:17 victor-pc kernel: [39301.633105] usb 3-4: New USB device found, idVendor=148f, idProduct=7601, bcdDevice= 0.00
Jun 20 22:24:17 victor-pc kernel: [39301.633109] usb 3-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jun 20 22:24:17 victor-pc kernel: [39301.633111] usb 3-4: Product: 802.11 n WLAN
Jun 20 22:24:17 victor-pc kernel: [39301.633112] usb 3-4: Manufacturer: MediaTek
Jun 20 22:24:17 victor-pc kernel: [39301.633114] usb 3-4: SerialNumber: 1.0
Jun 20 22:24:18 victor-pc kernel: [39302.251494] usb 3-4: reset high-speed USB device number 117 using xhci_hcd
Jun 20 22:24:19 victor-pc kernel: [39302.885911] mt7601u 3-4:1.0: ASIC revision: 76010001 MAC revision: 76010500
Jun 20 22:24:19 victor-pc kernel: [39302.918371] mt7601u 3-4:1.0: EEPROM ver:0d fae:00
Jun 20 22:24:19 victor-pc kernel: [39303.137789] ieee80211 phy117: Selected rate control algorithm 'minstrel_ht'
Jun 20 22:24:19 victor-pc kernel: [39303.150862] mt7601u 3-4:1.0 wlx20e71702e354: renamed from wlan0
Jun 20 22:24:19 victor-pc kernel: [39303.202501] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx20e71702e354: link is not ready
Jun 20 22:24:19 victor-pc kernel: [39303.229189] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx20e71702e354: link is not ready
Jun 20 22:24:19 victor-pc kernel: [39303.261362] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx20e71702e354: link is not ready
Jun 20 22:24:19 victor-pc kernel: [39303.353865] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx20e71702e354: link is not ready
Jun 20 22:29:19 victor-pc kernel: [39602.980528] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx20e71702e354: link is not ready
Jun 20 22:34:22 victor-pc kernel: [39906.175857] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx20e71702e354: link is not ready
Jun 20 22:36:42 victor-pc kernel: [40046.142081] mt7601u 3-4:1.0: Error: RX urb failed:-71
Jun 20 22:36:42 victor-pc kernel: [40046.142145] mt7601u 3-4:1.0: Error: RX urb failed:-71
Jun 20 22:36:42 victor-pc kernel: [40046.142152] usb 3-4: USB disconnect, device number 117
Jun 20 22:36:42 victor-pc kernel: [40046.142225] mt7601u 3-4:1.0: Error: RX urb failed:-71
Jun 20 22:36:42 victor-pc kernel: [40046.142305] mt7601u 3-4:1.0: Error: RX urb failed:-71
Jun 20 22:36:43 victor-pc kernel: [40047.385534] usb 3-4: new high-speed USB device number 118 using xhci_hcd
Jun 20 22:36:47 victor-pc kernel: [40051.425583] usb 3-4: new high-speed USB device number 119 using xhci_hcd
Jun 20 22:36:49 victor-pc kernel: [40053.441513] usb 3-4: new high-speed USB device number 120 using xhci_hcd
Jun 20 22:37:02 victor-pc kernel: [40066.113480] usb 3-4: new high-speed USB device number 121 using xhci_hcd
Jun 20 22:37:03 victor-pc kernel: [40067.193513] usb 3-4: new high-speed USB device number 122 using xhci_hcd
Jun 20 22:37:04 victor-pc kernel: [40068.059580] usb 3-4: New USB device found, idVendor=148f, idProduct=7601, bcdDevice= 0.00
Jun 20 22:37:04 victor-pc kernel: [40068.059584] usb 3-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jun 20 22:37:04 victor-pc kernel: [40068.059586] usb 3-4: Product: 802.11 n WLAN
Jun 20 22:37:04 victor-pc kernel: [40068.059587] usb 3-4: Manufacturer: MediaTek
Jun 20 22:37:04 victor-pc kernel: [40068.059589] usb 3-4: SerialNumber: 1.0
Jun 20 22:37:05 victor-pc kernel: [40068.881619] usb 3-4: reset high-speed USB device number 122 using xhci_hcd
Jun 20 22:37:06 victor-pc kernel: [40069.936424] mt7601u 3-4:1.0: ASIC revision: 76010001 MAC revision: 76010500
Jun 20 22:37:06 victor-pc kernel: [40069.967968] mt7601u 3-4:1.0: EEPROM ver:0d fae:00
Jun 20 22:37:06 victor-pc kernel: [40070.194404] ieee80211 phy118: Selected rate control algorithm 'minstrel_ht'
Jun 20 22:37:06 victor-pc kernel: [40070.206559] mt7601u 3-4:1.0 wlx20e71702e354: renamed from wlan0
Jun 20 22:37:06 victor-pc kernel: [40070.239622] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx20e71702e354: link is not ready
Jun 20 22:37:06 victor-pc kernel: [40070.263749] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx20e71702e354: link is not ready
Jun 20 22:37:06 victor-pc kernel: [40070.295701] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx20e71702e354: link is not ready
Jun 20 22:37:06 victor-pc kernel: [40070.355150] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx20e71702e354: link is not ready
Jun 20 22:38:04 victor-pc kernel: [40128.251285] input: BC:F2:92:1C:63:D8 as /devices/virtual/input/input45
Jun 20 22:42:09 victor-pc kernel: [40373.322580] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx20e71702e354: link is not ready
Jun 20 22:46:47 victor-pc kernel: [40651.472599] usb 3-4: USB disconnect, device number 122
Jun 20 22:46:47 victor-pc kernel: [40651.472612] mt7601u 3-4:1.0: Error: RX urb failed:-71
Jun 20 22:46:47 victor-pc kernel: [40651.472684] mt7601u 3-4:1.0: Error: RX urb failed:-71
Jun 20 22:46:47 victor-pc kernel: [40651.472764] mt7601u 3-4:1.0: Error: RX urb failed:-71
Jun 20 22:46:48 victor-pc kernel: [40651.876413] usb 3-4: new high-speed USB device number 123 using xhci_hcd
Jun 20 22:46:55 victor-pc kernel: [40659.472401] usb 3-4: new high-speed USB device number 124 using xhci_hcd
Jun 20 22:46:59 victor-pc kernel: [40663.388386] usb 3-4: new high-speed USB device number 125 using xhci_hcd
Jun 20 22:47:02 victor-pc kernel: [40666.100387] usb 3-4: new high-speed USB device number 126 using xhci_hcd
Jun 20 22:47:03 victor-pc kernel: [40666.746509] usb 3-4: New USB device found, idVendor=148f, idProduct=7601, bcdDevice= 0.00
Jun 20 22:47:03 victor-pc kernel: [40666.746513] usb 3-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jun 20 22:47:03 victor-pc kernel: [40666.746515] usb 3-4: Product: 802.11 n WLAN
Jun 20 22:47:03 victor-pc kernel: [40666.746516] usb 3-4: Manufacturer: MediaTek
Jun 20 22:47:03 victor-pc kernel: [40666.746517] usb 3-4: SerialNumber: 1.0
Jun 20 22:47:03 victor-pc kernel: [40667.504493] mt7601u: probe of 3-4:1.0 failed with error -5
Jun 20 22:47:03 victor-pc kernel: [40667.504721] usb 3-4: USB disconnect, device number 126
Jun 20 22:47:08 victor-pc kernel: [40671.940336] usb 3-4: new high-speed USB device number 127 using xhci_hcd
Jun 20 22:47:11 victor-pc kernel: [40675.292366] usb 3-4: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Jun 20 22:47:13 victor-pc kernel: [40677.136363] usb 3-4: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
Jun 20 22:47:15 victor-pc kernel: [40679.724337] usb 3-4: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
Jun 20 22:47:17 victor-pc kernel: [40681.348339] usb 3-4: new high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
Jun 20 22:47:24 victor-pc kernel: [40687.800311] usb 3-4: new high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
Jun 20 22:47:28 victor-pc kernel: [40692.664327] usb 3-4: new high-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
Jun 20 22:47:32 victor-pc kernel: [40696.320321] usb 3-4: new high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
Jun 20 22:47:35 victor-pc kernel: [40698.836317] usb 3-4: new high-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
Jun 20 22:47:35 victor-pc kernel: [40699.692990] usb 3-4: New USB device found, idVendor=148f, idProduct=7601, bcdDevice= 0.00
Jun 20 22:47:35 victor-pc kernel: [40699.692996] usb 3-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jun 20 22:47:35 victor-pc kernel: [40699.692999] usb 3-4: Product: 802.11 n WLAN
Jun 20 22:47:35 victor-pc kernel: [40699.693001] usb 3-4: Manufacturer: MediaTek
Jun 20 22:47:35 victor-pc kernel: [40699.693004] usb 3-4: SerialNumber: 1.0
Jun 20 22:47:36 victor-pc kernel: [40700.456416] mt7601u: probe of 3-4:1.0 failed with error -5
Jun 20 22:47:36 victor-pc kernel: [40700.456647] usb 3-4: USB disconnect, device number 10
Jun 20 22:47:37 victor-pc kernel: [40700.816293] usb 3-4: new high-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
Jun 20 22:47:41 victor-pc kernel: [40705.620285] usb 3-4: new high-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
Jun 20 22:47:43 victor-pc kernel: [40707.156280] usb 3-4: new high-speed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
Jun 20 22:47:45 victor-pc kernel: [40709.648273] usb 3-4: new high-speed USB device number 14 using xhci_hcd
Jun 20 22:47:47 victor-pc kernel: [40710.928280] usb 3-4: new high-speed USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
Jun 20 22:47:47 victor-pc kernel: [40711.574445] usb 3-4: New USB device found, idVendor=148f, idProduct=7601, bcdDevice= 0.00
Jun 20 22:47:47 victor-pc kernel: [40711.574448] usb 3-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jun 20 22:47:47 victor-pc kernel: [40711.574450] usb 3-4: Product: 802.11 n WLAN
Jun 20 22:47:47 victor-pc kernel: [40711.574452] usb 3-4: Manufacturer: MediaTek
Jun 20 22:47:47 victor-pc kernel: [40711.574453] usb 3-4: SerialNumber: 1.0
Jun 20 22:47:48 victor-pc kernel: [40712.184432] usb 3-4: reset high-speed USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
Jun 20 22:47:48 victor-pc kernel: [40712.615363] mt7601u 3-4:1.0: ASIC revision: 76010001 MAC revision: 76010500
Jun 20 22:47:48 victor-pc kernel: [40712.646620] mt7601u 3-4:1.0: EEPROM ver:0d fae:00
Jun 20 22:47:49 victor-pc kernel: [40712.865642] ieee80211 phy121: Selected rate control algorithm 'minstrel_ht'
Jun 20 22:47:49 victor-pc kernel: [40712.881435] mt7601u 3-4:1.0 wlx20e71702e354: renamed from wlan0
Jun 20 22:47:49 victor-pc kernel: [40712.934087] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx20e71702e354: link is not ready
Jun 20 22:47:49 victor-pc kernel: [40712.954281] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx20e71702e354: link is not ready
Jun 20 22:47:49 victor-pc kernel: [40712.982407] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx20e71702e354: link is not ready
Jun 20 22:47:49 victor-pc kernel: [40713.084888] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx20e71702e354: link is not ready
Jun 20 22:51:32 victor-pc kernel: [40936.620155] Bluetooth: Unexpected continuation frame (len 0)
Jun 20 22:51:32 victor-pc kernel: [40936.622646] Bluetooth: Unexpected continuation frame (len 0)
Jun 20 22:51:32 victor-pc kernel: [40936.660176] Bluetooth: Unexpected continuation frame (len 0)
Jun 20 22:51:32 victor-pc kernel: [40936.661410] Bluetooth: Unexpected continuation frame (len 0)
Jun 20 22:51:33 victor-pc kernel: [40936.967665] Bluetooth: Unexpected continuation frame (len 0)
Jun 20 22:51:33 victor-pc kernel: [40936.968909] Bluetooth: Unexpected continuation frame (len 0)
Jun 20 22:51:33 victor-pc kernel: [40937.147647] Bluetooth: Unexpected continuation frame (len 0)
Jun 20 22:51:33 victor-pc kernel: [40937.148887] Bluetooth: Unexpected continuation frame (len 0)
Jun 20 22:51:33 victor-pc kernel: [40937.187763] Bluetooth: Unexpected continuation frame (len 0)
Jun 20 22:51:33 victor-pc kernel: [40937.190140] Bluetooth: Unexpected continuation frame (len 0)
Jun 20 22:51:33 victor-pc kernel: [40937.675167] Bluetooth: Unexpected continuation frame (len 0)
Jun 20 22:51:33 victor-pc kernel: [40937.677667] Bluetooth: Unexpected continuation frame (len 0)
Jun 20 22:51:34 victor-pc kernel: [40937.938901] Bluetooth: Unexpected continuation frame (len 0)
Jun 20 22:51:34 victor-pc kernel: [40937.940149] Bluetooth: Unexpected continuation frame (len 0)
Jun 20 22:51:34 victor-pc kernel: [40938.243903] Bluetooth: Unexpected continuation frame (len 0)
Jun 20 22:51:34 victor-pc kernel: [40938.246420] Bluetooth: Unexpected continuation frame (len 0)
Jun 20 22:51:34 victor-pc kernel: [40938.467672] Bluetooth: Unexpected continuation frame (len 0)
Jun 20 22:51:34 victor-pc kernel: [40938.468890] Bluetooth: Unexpected continuation frame (len 0)
Jun 20 22:51:34 victor-pc kernel: [40938.507696] Bluetooth: Unexpected continuation frame (len 0)
Jun 20 22:51:34 victor-pc kernel: [40938.508936] Bluetooth: Unexpected continuation frame (len 0)
Jun 20 22:51:34 victor-pc kernel: [40938.611424] Bluetooth: Unexpected continuation frame (len 0)
Jun 20 22:51:34 victor-pc kernel: [40938.612641] Bluetooth: Unexpected continuation frame (len 0)
Jun 20 22:51:34 victor-pc kernel: [40938.651441] Bluetooth: Unexpected continuation frame (len 0)
Jun 20 22:51:34 victor-pc kernel: [40938.652665] Bluetooth: Unexpected continuation frame (len 0)
Jun 20 22:51:34 victor-pc kernel: [40938.691489] Bluetooth: Unexpected continuation frame (len 0)
Jun 20 22:51:34 victor-pc kernel: [40938.692677] Bluetooth: Unexpected continuation frame (len 0)
Jun 20 22:51:35 victor-pc kernel: [40938.913935] Bluetooth: Unexpected continuation frame (len 0)
Jun 20 22:51:35 victor-pc kernel: [40938.917653] Bluetooth: Unexpected continuation frame (len 0)
Jun 20 22:51:35 victor-pc kernel: [40939.220154] Bluetooth: Unexpected continuation frame (len 0)
Jun 20 22:51:35 victor-pc kernel: [40939.221404] Bluetooth: Unexpected continuation frame (len 0)
Jun 20 22:51:35 victor-pc kernel: [40939.625165] Bluetooth: Unexpected continuation frame (len 0)
Jun 20 22:51:35 victor-pc kernel: [40939.628922] Bluetooth: Unexpected continuation frame (len 0)
Jun 20 22:51:36 victor-pc kernel: [40939.931414] Bluetooth: Unexpected continuation frame (len 0)
Jun 20 22:51:36 victor-pc kernel: [40939.933901] Bluetooth: Unexpected continuation frame (len 0)
Jun 20 22:51:36 victor-pc kernel: [40939.973942] Bluetooth: Unexpected continuation frame (len 0)
Jun 20 22:51:36 victor-pc kernel: [40939.976425] Bluetooth: Unexpected continuation frame (len 0)
Jun 20 22:51:36 victor-pc kernel: [40940.641405] Bluetooth: Unexpected continuation frame (len 0)
Jun 20 22:51:36 victor-pc kernel: [40940.645153] Bluetooth: Unexpected continuation frame (len 0)
Jun 20 22:51:37 victor-pc kernel: [40940.946394] Bluetooth: Unexpected continuation frame (len 0)
Jun 20 22:51:37 victor-pc kernel: [40940.948882] Bluetooth: Unexpected continuation frame (len 0)
Jun 20 22:51:37 victor-pc kernel: [40941.028904] Bluetooth: Unexpected continuation frame (len 0)
Jun 20 22:51:37 victor-pc kernel: [40941.036407] Bluetooth: Unexpected continuation frame (len 0)
Jun 20 22:51:37 victor-pc kernel: [40941.291387] Bluetooth: Unexpected continuation frame (len 0)
Jun 20 22:51:37 victor-pc kernel: [40941.295164] Bluetooth: Unexpected continuation frame (len 0)
Jun 20 22:51:38 victor-pc kernel: [40941.962672] Bluetooth: Unexpected continuation frame (len 0)
Jun 20 22:51:38 victor-pc kernel: [40941.965176] Bluetooth: Unexpected continuation frame (len 0)
Jun 20 22:51:38 victor-pc kernel: [40942.271430] Bluetooth: Unexpected continuation frame (len 0)
Jun 20 22:51:38 victor-pc kernel: [40942.273921] Bluetooth: Unexpected continuation frame (len 0)
Jun 20 22:51:38 victor-pc kernel: [40942.571332] Bluetooth: Unexpected continuation frame (len 0)
Jun 20 22:51:38 victor-pc kernel: [40942.572589] Bluetooth: Unexpected continuation frame (len 0)
Jun 20 22:52:52 victor-pc kernel: [41016.210516] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx20e71702e354: link is not ready
Jun 20 22:56:01 victor-pc kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 4.19.0-5-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 8.3.0 (Debian 8.3.0-7)) #1 SMP Debian 4.19.37-3 (2019-05-15)
Jun 20 22:56:01 victor-pc kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-5-amd64 root=UUID=10e94c88-754c-49c3-94db-b6d4a7d491cc ro quiet splash processor.max_cstate=0 rcu_nocbs=0-15
```

I believe that `Jun 20 22:52:52` was the time where my computer froze and I had to hard reset it since right after this line I saw the command line logging as you can see at `Jun 20 22:56:01`.

#### More about the hardware and software

```
OS: Debian 10 buster
Session type: Wayland (But also reproducible with X.org)
Desktop environment: GNOME version 3.30.2 (But also reproducible with GNOME version 3.22)
Kernel: x86_64 Linux 4.19.0-5-amd64
CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 1700 Eight-Core @ 16x 3.65GHz [46.0°C]
GPU: Radeon RX 590 Series (POLARIS10, DRM 3.27.0, 4.19.0-5-amd64, LLVM 7.0.1)
RAM: 16040MiB
```

```
# dmidecode 3.2
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.1.1 present.

Handle 0x0002, DMI type 2, 15 bytes
Base Board Information
    Manufacturer: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
    Product Name: PRIME B350-PLUS
    Version: Rev X.0x
    Serial Number: 170397794905599
    Asset Tag: Default string
    Features:
        Board is a hosting board
        Board is replaceable
    Location In Chassis: Default string
    Chassis Handle: 0x0003
    Type: Motherboard
    Contained Object Handles: 0
```

#### Kernel parameters

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash processor.max_cstate=0 rcu_nocbs=0-15"
```

#### Different graphics card but same problem

Before owning a Radeon RX 590, I owned a NVIDIA GTX 1050 (Model N105TD5-4GD, manufactured by Gigabyte). Which I had the same problem even more constantly (maybe due to the lack of the kernel parameters or so). My NVIDIA GTX 1050 eventually died some time after a year of usage. Not sure if it this is important but I think it's safer to mention it.

#### Cooling

I had a `WaterCooler CoolerMaster Masterliquid Lite 120V MLW-D12M-A20PW-R1` but since it was a little bit old and I'm scared of leaking and water damaging my CPU and motherboard, now I started using the Wraith Spire that came with my CPU. I honestly didn't notice much difference in terms of performance after the exchange.

#### Linux distributions in which I experienced the same issues

- Arch Linux
- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and Disco
- Debian 9 (with Linux 4.14, Linux 4.9 or Linux 5.1)
- Debian 10 (Buster)

I hope that somebody can help me. I've been facing this issue for years and I really don't want to quit Linux or even go back to Intel CPUs.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=196683 . Opened 2 years ago, last comment 2 days ago, 611 messages in the bug so far... have a good reading.

Answer (score 3):

Victor, my machine has almost the same configuration as yours and I have also tried to replace the Graphic card and different Linux flavors but the problem is still there. After a little research I figured out that it is a known problem at AMD and they also have a couple of bugs opened for that. Please take a look at [this](https://community.amd.com/thread/225795) link and also at [this](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/amd-ryzen-problems-and-fixes/55533) one, because there are a couple of people reporting that they have fixed their problem. I haven't tried it yet, I'm just about to format my computer to give a try, thus, good luck!

Answer (score 3):

As Rodrigo pointed out in his answer, that was indeed a problem in the processor. I contacted them and in a couple of weeks the problem was solved.

Unfortunately they were out of the same processors (Ryzen 7 1700) to give me a new one, so they gave my money back. It was very fast and professional. I bought a Ryzen 5 2600x now and I'm very satisfied with my new processor. Fortunately, I no longer have problems of the kind again. Linux or Windows, everything works just fine.

Answer (score 3):

The question is quite old, but I had the same issue just now and was able to solve it. Threads linked by Rodrigo have the answer, but it's over 13 pages of discussion. In interest of time, here's a summary of proposed solutions:

- you need to update your BIOS and set PSU Idle to `Typical Current Idle` (this is critical)
- kernel parameters for both your computer *and all Virtual Machines running on it*: `idle=nomwait`, `processor.max_cstate=5`
- kernel version is important too. Since I am writing this in 2020, make sure you are using the most recent stable kernel

I had another problem with my Ryzen processor preventing it from booting linux at all. The solution was to add another kernel boot param: `iommu=soft`. I also tried `iommu=pt`, which works, but I do see some `AMDVi` timout events.

Unfortunately, Ryzen processors are still a mess in 2020.

Comment: Ryzen still buggy in 2020?  In thought this issue was fixed in HW since Ryzen 3000-series (and in SW since Linux 5.something).

Comment: My Ryzen 7 1700X still needs workarounds mentioned in the answer to work.